# Issue when deploying custom mediators in WSO2 ESB.Hi

Tags: wso2, esb, classnotfound

I have created a custom mediator. when I deploy the jar in /repository/components/lib' folder, it is throwing the following exception. Please check the code and exception below.

I copied synapse-core_2.1.2.wso2v2 in component/lib /component/dropins, but that did not help. I dont think I need to to copy these libraries, as they are core libraries which are part of WSO2 ESB.

Can someone help us why it is throwing this exception? I have created this Mediators in developer studio and created the jar. It should deploy without any issue.

Code:

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext synCtx) { 

    SynapseLog synLog = getLog(synCtx);

    if (synLog.isTraceOrDebugEnabled()) {
        synLog.traceOrDebug("Start : Cache mediator");

        if (synLog.isTraceTraceEnabled()) {
            synLog.traceTrace("Message : " + synCtx.getEnvelope());
        }
    }

    ConfigurationContext cfgCtx =
            ((Axis2MessageContext) synCtx).getAxis2MessageContext().getConfigurationContext();
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/synapse/core/axis2/Axis2MessageContext
        at com.span.custom.cache.DistributedCacheMediator.mediate(DistributedCacheMediator.java:82)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:78)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom jar go to repository/components/lib only if you have developed a custom class mediator

If you have developed a real mediator (with a specific name that you can use inside your mediation, and it's serializer & factory, and it' entries MediatorFactory & MediatorSerializer in META-INF/services), you must generate a jar with maven-bundle-plugin that go to repository/components/dropins

Comment: Thanks for the response Michel.  Appreciated.

Comment: Axis2MessageContext is a system class from synapse-core_2.1.2.wso2v4.jar library. This jar is already present in patches folder.  I have removed this system jars from dropins and lib folders and restarted ESB, but still i get this exception. Is it related to jars conflict? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Just to clarify,   'Axis2MessageContext' is referred in my Class mediator.

Comment: I use Axis2MessageContext in a custom mediator (real mediator, not a class mediator) without problem in ESB v4.8.1   I can find this class in repository/components/plugins/synapse-core_2.1.2.wso2v4.jar.   The jar you can find in 'patchxxxx' directories are copied in components/plugins by the ESB at startup. My custom mediator is in a jar made in commande line with maven, can't help you with developer studio, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Michel. Looks like, it is something related to Jars version conflicts.

Comment: I  used WSo2 ESB 4.9.0 instead of 4.8.1. The issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I used WSo2 ESB 4.9.0 instead of 4.8.1. The issue is resolved.